# Subsequent changes to file after "git add"

Tags: git

git newbie here, bear with me if this is trivial. I cannot find this in some git basic docs seen so far.

I did a "git add file1" which puts the file into the index. Immediately after this the "git diff --cahced" shows correct diff content.

Then I made some more changes to file1. Now "git diff --cached" shows the previously shown diff content, and new changes are not being displayed. This makes me believe that the index is having the snapshot of the file1 contents when I did the "git add", in other words, when I staged the file.

Is this correct? And will subsequent commit will only commit what "git diff --cached" is showing me, or all my changes till the commit is issued?

Comment: I was at work when I noticed this and was planning to clarify myself from documentation over the wkend. Will try next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the whole point of index – it contains changes to be commited. If you don't use `-a`, `git commit` will create a commit whose content (the tree) will be what was in the index.

What `git add` does is that is copies the file (or directory) from the working copy into the index.

One way this can be useful is `git add -p`: it lets you see changes to a file and adds a version of the file with only changes you chose to the index.

Comment: "What git add does is that is copies the file" -- ah, my idea on 'git add' was it adds the file to the list of files to be commited. Thanks for the clarification! Now I have a better picture of the work-area vs. staging-area.